# bulma html does not display as expect even though the code is entered properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, navbar

I am newbie with Rails and here is my problem

I created a rails program by this command

```
rails new freelancer -d=postgresql --javascript=webpack
```

And I had no problem

I wanted to use bulma extension in my rails program and I added these line to the gemfile

```
gem 'bulma-rails', '~> 0.9.4'
gem 'bulma-extensions-rails', '~> 1.0.30'
```

and these lines to the app -> assets -> stylesheets -> application.css

```
@import 'bulma';
@import 'bulma-extensions';
```

then I ran these commands

```
bundle install;
yarn add jquery;
```

and I had no error.

I created a rails page by this command

```
rails g controller pages home
```

and add the bulma code to the app -> views -> layouts -> application.html.erb file

Here is my application.html.erb file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Freelancer</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
<div class="navbar-brand">
<a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
  <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
</a>
<a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
</div>
<div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
<div class="navbar-start">
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-item">
    Documentation
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
    <a class="navbar-link">
      More
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        About
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Jobs
      </a>
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Contact
      </a>
      <hr class="navbar-divider">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Report an issue
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar-end">
  <div class="navbar-item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="button is-primary">
        <strong>Sign up</strong>
      </a>
      <a class="button is-light">
        Log in
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought that my home page must be the design as here

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/

, but it liked this

[my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUEpC.png)

I did not know why it became like this ? Could you please give me some advice for my problem ? Here is my code, if you need for reference

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer01
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I cloned your repo locally and it seems that you're using SASS directives while the app is configured for CSS only.

I fixed the issue by replacing `application.css` content with:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS (and SCSS, if configured) file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bulma
 *= require bulma-extensions
 */
```

Here is the result:
[image]